# Sharepoint foundation 2013: digital asset content types not available

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, foundation

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2013. I want to save video type documents on my site, but I can't make it work, that content type does not appear on the list. I searched for the "digital asset content types" on my site, but again, is not there.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the "Video" content type, you first must set the Site Collection Feature named "Video and Rich Media" (NOTE: Site Collection, not Site, feature).  See more: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Activate-video-and-rich-media-features-for-a-site-collection-db710101-a4fd-42ca-b9e0-7f6554c522ab